# QuoteLineItem not associated with Quote

Tags: apex

For some reason this fails - q.QuoteLineItems is null. Can someone tell me why?

```
@isTest
private class QuoteTest {

   static Account A;
   static Opportunity o;
   static Quote q;
   static Product2 p;
   static PriceBookEntry pe;
   static OpportunityLineItem oli;
   static QuoteLineItem qli;

   static {
       a = new Account(name = 'Test account', Jurisdiction__c = 'Denmark', currencyIsoCode = 'DKK');
       insert a;

       o = new Opportunity(name = 'Test opportunity', AccountId = a.id, closeDate = date.today(), stageName = 'Demonstration Scheduled');
       insert o;

       p = new Product2(name = 'Test product', type__c = 'Subscription', limits__c='a;b\nc;d');
       insert p;

       Id pbId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();

       pe = new PriceBookEntry(PriceBook2Id = pbId, Product2Id = p.id, UnitPrice = 100, IsActive = true);
       insert pe;

       oli = new OpportunityLineItem(OpportunityId = o.id, Quantity = 1, PricebookEntryId = pe.id, totalPrice = 200);
       insert oli;

       q = new Quote(name = 'Test quote', OpportunityId = o.id, PriceBook2Id = pbId);
       insert q;

       qli = new QuoteLineItem(QuoteId = q.id, PriceBookentryId = pe.Id, Quantity = 1, UnitPrice = 1);
       insert qli; 
       System.debug(q);
       System.debug(qli);
       System.debug(q.QuoteLineItems);
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try requerying quote and then do the system.debug

Comment: How do I do that? :-) Noob here.

Comment: @karthikselva s answer is what i wanted you to try.

Comment: @Prady It didn't do the trick, I'm afraid. It's very weird.

Comment: Strange, that should be giving out an output. What is failing? Are you still getting null?

Comment: @Prady Yes - you can see the debug result in the screen shot I added.

Comment: if you can see the result, what is the issue? Isnt this you wanted to see?

Comment: @Prady no - as you can see the last debug is empty - this is because q.QuoteLineItems is null. And this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**q** is just an in-memory object and doesn't have enough knowledge on the child object added after it in the database.

Try this:

```
   q = [Select Id, (select Id From QuoteLineItems) From Quote where Id = :Id];
```

After performing the insert of quoteLineItems. Now:

```
   System.debug(q.QuoteLineItems);
```

Should not be null

Modified Code:

```
@isTest
private class QuoteTest {

   static Account A;
   static Opportunity o;
   static Quote q;
   static Product2 p;
   static PriceBookEntry pe;
   static OpportunityLineItem oli;
   static QuoteLineItem qli;

   static {
       a = new Account(name = 'Test account', Jurisdiction__c = 'Denmark', currencyIsoCode = 'DKK');
       insert a;

       o = new Opportunity(name = 'Test opportunity', AccountId = a.id, closeDate = date.today(), stageName = 'Demonstration Scheduled');
       insert o;

       p = new Product2(name = 'Test product', type__c = 'Subscription', limits__c='a;b\nc;d');
       insert p;

       Id pbId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();

       pe = new PriceBookEntry(PriceBook2Id = pbId, Product2Id = p.id, UnitPrice = 100, IsActive = true);
       insert pe;

       oli = new OpportunityLineItem(OpportunityId = o.id, Quantity = 1, PricebookEntryId = pe.id, totalPrice = 200);
       insert oli;

       q = new Quote(name = 'Test quote', OpportunityId = o.id, PriceBook2Id = pbId);
       insert q;

       qli = new QuoteLineItem(QuoteId = q.id, PriceBookentryId = pe.Id, Quantity = 1, UnitPrice = 1);
       insert qli; 

       // Reloading data back from database
       q = [Select Id, (select Id from QuoteLineItems) From Quote Where Id = :q.Id];

       System.debug(q);
       System.debug(qli);
       System.debug(q.QuoteLineItems);
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry - that didn't help. See the debug log in the original question.

Comment: Did you try the modified code ?

Comment: Yes - still the same.

Comment: BTW. It also fails my test where I test a controller's ability to get the QuoteLineItems and I imagine that the controller does it's own query at runtime.

Comment: Thats really weird. Can you check whats the childrens name you have provided for QuoteLineItem in Quote object definition ?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want me to do? Can you rephrase?

Answer (score 0):

This did it:

```
q = [select Id,Name,(select id,QuoteId,PriceBookentryId,Quantity,UnitPrice,Product2Id,Product2.Limits__c,Product2.Type__c FROM QuoteLineItems) From Quote WHERE Id=:q.id];
```